# How to avoid end user actions based on stale data in DB

Tags: mysql, django, database

I have a database table at the backend, that provides various items for sale and their prices as well. For the sake of simplicity, let us assume that the schema for the same is like so:-

```
class Product(models.Model):
    item_id = models.Integer()
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    item_price = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    item_count = models.Integer()
```

There is an API `getProducts()`, that is used to show to the enduser all the products available, including their price.

There is another API `buyProduct(product_id)`, exposed to the enduser, using which he may purchase the item after seeing its price. There is a third API, `updatePrice(product_id, new_price)` available to the administration backend using which the price may be modified.

Now w/o having a database transaction that spans across >1 HTTP requests, how can I ensure that the API `buyProduct()` succeeds only if the price is the same as what the enduser saw (basically whatever `getProducts()` had returned last to the browser). It is possible that a customer sees the price of a product as 1$, and clicks BUY, but simultaneously the price at the backend was changed to 2$.

I have two solutions:-

1. Fix the `buyProduct()` API to include a price, which indicates
   whichever price that was shown to the enduser. If the product price
   has changed, throw an error.
2. Include a GUID against the products which represents the version of
   the product row. This is then carried all the way to the enduser's
   browser(but not shown to the user), and quoted in the `buyProduct()`
   also. Anytime there is a modification to any row in the Products
   table, the GUID will get updated. `buyProduct()` will ensure that at
   the time the API is executed, the product's GUID should be what the
   API carried.

I believe <2> is the way to go, since even the `item_count` is prone to change. But is this how everyone does things? Is there a django pattern to solve this?

Just realised that the E-Tag header and the Cache-Control headers in HTTP seem to be a recommended way to avoid data corruption. But do folks really follow this way? I found a link about this [here](https://www.kennethlange.com/avoid-data-corruption-in-your-rest-api-with-etags/)

Comment: There isn't any specific "django-pattern" that I know of. The common generic patterns are indeed to use some marker - a timestamp, a hash of the relevant data, a GUID, whatever as long as you can use it to detect stale data. I most often use a hash since it makes sure the difference is relevant (at least based on the values used for hashing).

Comment: Is the E-Tag a better way to solve this?

Comment: It's a bit orthogonal - etags are, mainly, for cache handling at the HTTP level - and you need to generate them anyway (=> "Common methods of ETag generation include using a collision-resistant hash function of the resource's content, a hash of the last modification timestamp, or even just a revision number." - which is just what I mentionned actually), so IMHO the only things you'll get with etags are more complication and less control.